# nHibernate safe delete

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, ado.net

**Is there any way to check if it is safe to delete record from table ?**

for example :

```
daoStudent.Delete(id);
```

doesn't throw exception if it has any child records , but I would like it to. I could take other actions like making student inactive.

Comment: What do you mean? If you use a foreign key, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: No it does not. nH makes rollback.

Comment: Are you using foreign key? Are you cascading deletes to child collections? in other words...post your student mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it ,

```
SomeStudentRelation.HasItems()
```

to check if it has any child records.